# How to print out from cgridview to csv?

Tags: php, csv, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

Q : How to print out the filtered data from cgridview to csv?

Status : I followed instruction as [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/306/exporting-cgridview-results-to-csv-file/). But now I got the plane csv(excel) file. No header, no data.

This is view

```
<?php
echo CHtml::button('Export', array('id'=>'export-button','class'=>'span-3 button')); 
?>
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'request-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->creator(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            'request_no',
            array(
                  'name'=>'request_type_id',
                  'value'=>'$data->requesttypes->name',
            ),
            array(
                  'name'=>'request_category_id',
                  'value'=>'$data->requestcategories->name',
            ),
            array(
                  'name'=>'financial_type_id',
                  'value'=>'$data->requestfinanicaltypes->name',
            ),
            array(
                  'name'=>'urgency_id',
                  'value'=>'$data->requesturgent->name',
            ),
            'status',
            'eta_date',
            'completed_date',
            'created_date',

            array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update}{view}{copy}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                    'delete'=>array(
                        'visible'=>'true',
                        'options'=>array('style'=>'align:left;'),
                    ),
                    'view'=>array(
                        'visible'=>'true',
                        'options'=>array('style'=>'align:left;'),
                    ),              
                    'update'=>array(
                        'visible'=>'$data->status == \'Pending\'',
                    ),
                    'copy'=>array(
                        'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/assets/Copy2.png',      
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("creator/copy", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                        'options'=>array('style'=>'border:none;'),
                    ),
                ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                    'style'=>'text-align: right; padding-right:3px;'
                            ),
            ),
        ),
    )); ?>


    <?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('delete-item', "

    $('#export-button').on('click',function() {

        $.fn.yiiGridView.export();
    });
    $.fn.yiiGridView.export = function() {
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('request-grid',{ 
            success: function() {
                $('#request-grid').removeClass('grid-view-loading');
                window.location = '". $this->createUrl('exportFile')  . "';
            },
            data: 'export=true'
        });
    }
    ");
    ?>
```

This is My controller

```
public function actionExport()
{
    $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w');

    /* 
     * Write a header of csv file
     */
    $headers = array(
        'request_no',               
        'status',
        'eta_date',
        'completed_date',
        'created_date',
    );
    $row = array();
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        $row[] = Request::model()->getAttributeLabel($header);
    }
    fputcsv($fp,$row);

    /*
     * Init dataProvider for first page
     */
    $model=new Request('Creator');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Request'])) {
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Request'];
    }
    $dp = $model->search();

    /*
     * Get models, write to a file, then change page and re-init DataProvider
     * with next page and repeat writing again
     */
    while($models = $dp->getData()) {
        foreach($models as $model) {
            $row = array();
            foreach($headers as $head) {
                $row[] = CHtml::value($model,$head);
            }
            fputcsv($fp,$row);
        }

        unset($model,$dp,$pg);
        $model=new Request('Creator');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Request']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Request'];

        $dp = $model->search();
        $nextPage = $dp->getPagination()->getCurrentPage()+1;
        $dp->getPagination()->setCurrentPage($nextPage);
    }

    /*
     * save csv content to a Session
     */
    rewind($fp);
    Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile('aa.csv', stream_get_contents($fp), "text/csv", false);
    //Yii::app()->user->setState('export',stream_get_contents($fp));
    fclose($fp);
}

public function actionExportFile()
{
    Yii::app()->request->sendFile('export.csv',Yii::app()->user->getState('export'));
    Yii::app()->user->clearState('export');
}
```

Where did I wrong?

========================
updated

I moved to another extension [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/csvexport/) and followed by CalCS at [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16402-cgridview-and-phpexcel/)

Now I'm stacking to export the relationship data and some of the field are keep the data by csv and jason. I don't know to export those data at report. please help me.

this is my Model

```
public function creator()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('request_no',$this->request_no,true);
        //$criteria->condition('creator',$this->creator);

        $criteria->condition = 'creator =' . Yii::app()->user->id;


        $criteria->compare('request_type_id',$this->request_type_id);
        $criteria->compare('request_category_id',$this->request_category_id);
        $criteria->compare('financial_type_id',$this->financial_type_id);
        $criteria->compare('urgency_id',$this->urgency_id);
        $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);
        $criteria->compare('eta_cost_usd',$this->eta_cost_usd,true);
        $criteria->compare('eta_cost_kyats',$this->eta_cost_kyats,true);
        $criteria->compare('final_cost_Ks',$this->final_cost_Ks,true);
        $criteria->compare('final_cost_USD',$this->final_cost_USD,true);
        $criteria->compare('exchange_rate_Ks',$this->exchange_rate_Ks);
        $criteria->compare('exchange_date',$this->exchange_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
        $criteria->compare('reviewers',$this->reviewers,true);
        $criteria->compare('approvers',$this->approvers,true);
        $criteria->compare('approved_date',$this->approved_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('force_approved',$this->force_approved);
        $criteria->compare('implementers',$this->implementers);
        $criteria->compare('eta_date',$this->eta_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('completed_date',$this->completed_date,true);
        //$criteria->compare('created_date',$this->created_date,true);

        $criteria->order = ' created_date DESC';
         $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                        'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',
                                                                        Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
                        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                ));
        $_SESSION['Lectivo-excel']=$data; // get all data and filtered data :)

        /*return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
        */
        return $data;
    }
```

This is my View

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'request-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->creator(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        //'id',
        'request_no',
        //'creator',
        array(
              'name'=>'request_type_id',
              'value'=>'$data->requesttypes->name',
        ),
        array(
              'name'=>'request_category_id',
              'value'=>'$data->requestcategories->name',
        ),
        array(
              'name'=>'financial_type_id',
              'value'=>'$data->requestfinanicaltypes->name',
        ),
        array(
              'name'=>'urgency_id',
              'value'=>'$data->requesturgent->name',
        ),
        'status',
        'eta_date',
        'completed_date',
        'created_date',
        /*
        'description',
        'eta_cost_usd',
        'eta_cost_kyats',
        'final_cost_Ks',
        'final_cost_USD',
        'exchange_rate_Ks',
        'exchange_date',
        'status_id',
        'reviewers',
        'approvers',
        'approved_date',
        'force_approved',
        'implementer',
        'eta_date',
        'completed_date',
        'created_date',
        */
        array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{update}{view}{copy}',
        'buttons'=>array(
                'delete'=>array(
                    'visible'=>'true',
                    'options'=>array('style'=>'align:left;'),
                ),
                'view'=>array(
                    'visible'=>'true',
                    'options'=>array('style'=>'align:left;'),
                ),              
                'update'=>array(
                    'visible'=>'$data->status == \'Pending\'',
                ),
                'copy'=>array(
                    'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/assets/Copy2.png',      
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("creator/copy", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options'=>array('style'=>'border:none;'),
                ),
            ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                'style'=>'text-align: right; padding-right:3px;'
                        ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>

</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>

<div id='menub'>
<?php   
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
'encodeLabel'=>false,
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'actions'),
'items'=>array(
               array(
                     'label'=>Yii::t('internationalization', 'Exportar'),
                    'url'=>array('CREATOR/Excel'),


))));
?></div></div>
```

This is My controller

```
public function actionExcel() {

        $d = $_SESSION['Lectivo-excel'];

        $data = array();

        $data[]=array_keys($d->data[0]->attributes);//headers: cols name

        foreach ($d->data as $item) {
            $data[] = $item->attributes;

        }

        Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel.JPhpExcel');
        $xls = new JPhpExcel('UTF-8', false, 'test');
        $xls->addArray($data);
        $xls->generateXML('filename'); //export into a .xls file
    }
```

Comment: Check attribute rules for `Creator` scenario `$model=new Request('Creator');`. In instruction $model=new Request('search');

Comment: Thx Sergey I create the scenario as you. $model->scenario = "CreatorIndex"; at actionIndex(). And array('id, ...., created_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'CreatorIndex'), at my model rules(). and I changed $model=new Request('CreatorIndex'); at actionExport(). but still print out plane csv file. pls help me to solve this one. Thank you for your helping me :)

Comment: do you get data on pure cgridview? if you are, than you have to check your model rules.

Comment: Yes I get the data on my cgridview, displaying and filtering is working fine. I added array('id, ...., created_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'CreatorIndex'), But not working. How could I do?

Comment: Show your rule of 'CreatorIndex'

Comment: array('id, request_no, creator, request_type_id, request_category_id, financial_type_id, urgency_id, description, eta_cost_usd, eta_cost_kyats, final_cost_Ks, final_cost_USD, exchange_rate_Ks, exchange_date, status, reviewers, approvers, approved_date, force_approved, implementers, eta_date, completed_date, created_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'CreatorIndex'),

Comment: Hi Sergey, I updated my Question. pls help me. I'm stacking the report in 2 days. I didn't find a good solution till now. I need your help, I need the whole stackoverflow's members help.

Answer (score 0):

This is model (aaa.php)

```
public function creator()

    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);

        ...........

        $criteria->order = ' created_date DESC';
         $data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                    'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',
                                                                    Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));
        $_SESSION['excel-current']=$data; // get all data and filtered data :)

        return $data;
    }
```

This is controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model=new Request('creator');
        $model->scenario = "CreatorIndex";
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Request']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Request'];

        $this->render('index',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
public function actionExcel() {

        $d = $_SESSION['excel-current'];

        $data = array();
        //$data[]=array_keys($d->data[0]->attributes);//headers: default cols name

        // default data add
        foreach ($d->data as $item) {
            $data[] = $item->attributes;

        }

        // Custome cols
        $data[0][0] = 'Request No';

        .............

        $data[0][20] = 'Created Date';
        $i=1;

                // custom add data
        foreach($d->data as $item)
        {

            $data[$i][0] = $item->request_no;

                        ............

            $data[$i][20] = $item->created_date;
            $i++;
        }

        Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel.JPhpExcel');
        $xls = new JPhpExcel('UTF-8', false, 'test');
        $xls->addArray($data);
        $xls->generateXML('filename'); //export into a .xls file
    }
```

This is [phpexcel](http://www.mediafire.com/?63pi7byoo99d657) what I use. (not full phpexcel lib from their website.)

at views/aaa/index.php call the ?r=aaa/excel, this will be export your current filtered data or 1st page of data.