# Yii - Get all data of filtered CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I got a question about the `CGridView` in Yii. The case is that I want to export the current filtered data of all pages within a `CGridView` to an excel sheet. Now the problem is that I am getting the id's of each row within the gridview with jQuery. This means that only the rows that are currently visible on the page of a pagination are sent to the excel generator and not the ones that are at another pages.

My question is, is there a way within Yii to get all the data from all paginated pages from a `CGridView` in some kind of object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562626/yii-how-to-print-out-from-cgridview-to-csv

Comment: Is the export code written in PHP or in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the `$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(containerID)` to retrieve the key values of the selected rows in jQuery. And then you can post your results and retrieve the exported file for downloading.