# Passing items from CGridView to another view in Yii

Tags: view, yii, filter, controller, cgridview

I have a view with a CGridView which has also some filtering. I'd like to pass the items from CGridView (or their ids) to another view (of the same controller) where they'll be processed.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395539/yii-get-all-data-of-filtered-cgridview) about exporting the data, there's some JQuery selector, but I guess I should pass the ids to action in controller. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Bulk Actions of TbExtendedGridView in YiiBooster http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html#extendedgridview

I'm using it for my project as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'd like to ask, is it possible to get all the items, not only checked? Will it also work when there'll be more pages with items?